# Jackson Array Elements to POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize an existing JSON document using Jackson, and was wondering if it was possible to perform the following translation without resorting to a stack of custom deserialization.

The input JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "foo",
    "content": ["a", "b", {"some": "object", "goes": "here"}, 4]
}
```

The first 3 elements in `content` don't change, and are always String, String, SomeDataStructure, Integer (optional)

And I would like to deserialize into something like this:

```
class Foo {
    public static class FooContent {
        String some;
        String goes;
    }

    String aString;
    String bString;
    FooContent content;
    Integer cInt;      
}
```

Now I've already come across BeanAsArrayDeserializer, which *sounds* like it might be what I want, but I can't seem to find anything even remotely like a piece of example code to get me started.

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement your custom deserializer. See below source code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

;

public class JacksonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"type\": \"foo\",\"content\": [\"a\", \"b\", {\"some\": \"object\", \"goes\": \"here\"}, 4]}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, true);

        Root pojo = mapper.readValue(json, Root.class);
        System.out.println(pojo);
    }
}

class Root {
    public String type;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = FooDeserializer.class)
    public Foo content;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content.toString();
    }
}

class Foo {
    public static class FooContent {
        public String some;
        public String goes;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + some + ", " + goes + "}";
        }
    }

    String aString;
    String bString;
    FooContent content;
    Integer cInt;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo [aString=" + aString + ", bString=" + bString + ", content=" + content
                + ", cInt=" + cInt + "]";
    }
}

class FooDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Foo> {

    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        int index = 0;
        while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            JsonToken token = jp.getCurrentToken();
            if (token.isStructStart()) {
                f.content = jp.readValueAs(Foo.FooContent.class);
                index++;
            } else {
                switch (index++) {
                case 0:
                    f.aString = jp.getText();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    f.bString = jp.getText();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    f.cInt = Integer.parseInt(jp.getText());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

Above app prints:

```
Foo [aString=a, bString=b, content={object, here}, cInt=4]
```

Comment: Nice code snippet Michal. Looks like it would only work for single depth arrays though. Do you happen to know of a trivial approach to tracking nested array indices without a dictionary of some sort to keep track of array/object depth? Have been thinking of this for awhile and a lead might help.

Comment: Above code is custom implementation which fits only to above data structure. If we want to write more general solution we have to write probably new array deserializer and try to configure it and add indexing for properties. (Deserializer has to know what to expect). You could create new question on SO with example `JSON` and `POJO` structures.

Answer (score 0):

The feature that allows to use the `BeanAsArrayDeserializer` (internally) is `@JsonFormat`. You can read some information about it in [this](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/serializing-java-pojo-as-json-array-with-jackson-2-more-compact-output-510a85c019d4) blog post.

I also just learned about it recently, but I think a mapping that works for your case would look something like the following. You'd need a wrapper to hold the `content` field though, which would then be of type `Foo`.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "aString", "bString", "content", "cInt" })
class Foo {
    public static class FooContent {
        String some;
        String goes;
    }

    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING)
    String aString;

    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING)
    String bString;

    FooContent content;

    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.NUMBER)
    Integer cInt;      
}
```